# Why aren't my floated DIVS lining up?

Tags: css, positioning

Maybe it's because I've been coding a page from a mockup since 10am and now it's 1:30am, but what am I not doing to get the 3 divs to all line up beside eachother with a margin of 13px between them? The last 2 float as they should, but the first one is problematic. Any help is appreciated.

the page is here and the 3 divs are at the bottom and are white with blue  hyperlink titles: http://sni-stage.scholastic.com/ezpublisher/index.cfm

my css is:

```
.box1 {
   width:285px;
   height:141px;
   float:-left;
   background-image:url('/resource/uploads_scope/issues/images/at_A_glance_bottomBox.png');
}

.box2 {
   width:285px;
   height:141px;
   float:right;
   margin-left:13px;
   background-image:url('/resource/uploads_scope/issues/images/at_A_glance_bottomBox.png');
}

.box3 {
   width:285px;
   height:141px;
   float:right;
   margin-left:13px;
   background-image:url('/resource/uploads_scope/issues/images/at_A_glance_bottomBox.png');
}
```

Thanks for any help :-)

Comment: `float:-left` doesn't exist.

Comment: The link you posted doesn't seem to have the boxes on it, I assume you have to login. could you post the HTML that's around these too?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this was a typo on here only. but `float: -left` in box1 i think should be `float:left`

Comment: thanks! that was in the actual CSS too, but now I cant get them to align still. the last 2 are kicked way to the right and stacked on top of each other :-\

Comment: if the divs on the right are stacking, then there's a good chance it's because they don't have the space to sit next to each other and they are float:right - jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Fjzpm/

Comment: I have them display:inline-block; now so I'm going to check the width of the container they sit in

Comment: Not sure what I'm missing, but there is plenty room in the container div in which the boxes sit, even with the margins considered. However the last box will not align up to the top of the other boxes (divs).

Comment: are you able to show the html that goes with it? might be easier to see

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [display:inline-block](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/), instead of floats.

Comment: so just put that in each of the DIVs? display:inline-block?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, agreed. float: -left seems to be the problem. Also, please take care when calculating the width of your boxes. If you have these 3 boxes wrapped in a bigger div, then width of big div should at least be > (285*3) + (13*2). 13 being the margin left on 2 of the divs.

Comment: that math consideration is true. I thought that might be the case, as I think it is now that I used display:inline-block, and the last div is on the next line.

Comment: I have that but now it seems the last one just div wont align up top. I'll figure that in the morning.

Comment: Another good thing you can do is to first set the background colour of each div different. So keep the main background white and box1 red, box2 green and box3 yellow .. something like that. Then you will be able to see the size of your boxes. Also display: inline-block is important for horizontal alignment as Colin has mentioned below.